# Nothing to repeat Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting the error "Nothing to repeat" **/^[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+[^A-Za-z0-9]+{8,}$/** when I run this through a string.match() function or when using http://jsregex.com (you can simply copy paste the code in). The regex is trying to make sure the string is at least 8 characters long, include a lowercase a-z, uppercase a-z, at least one digit and one non letter/number (a special character).

Previous posts mention special characters but I've not got any in this pattern so a bit confused why its not working.

Comment: The problem is that you apply two quantifiers (`+`, `{8,}`) to one expression. It must have only one quantifier

Comment: Even if you correct your regex by making it `/^[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+[^A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$/` I suspect it is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*([^\w]|_)).{8,}
```

The above is the regex you need. You've two quantifiers, which is causing the error.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/iL0hZ4/2)

Comment: When I try this on jsregex.com the above code appears to match even "deFs.0" but that is not 8 characters? But I agree your demo does work.

Comment: Super thanks - and although the reputation isn't really needed - have some anyway :)

Comment: @Ukuser32 glad to have helped you! But Reputation is *really* needed for me at least till I get to reach 20k :p

Answer (score 4):

Lose the `+` before the `{8,}`. They are redundant.

The `{8,}` is trying to repeat something that came before. Since it's a `+`, it has nothing to repeat. Hence the error. You would get the same thing if you tried `a++`, or `a{1}{2}`, or any combination of repeaters (quantifiers) immediately adjacent to each other.

However, as a commenter rightly said, even if you get your regexp to compile, it's fundamentally broken in terms of what you want to accomplish.

It seems much easier, readable, and maintainable to simply say

```
/[a-z]/.test(str) && 
/[A-Z]/.test(str) && 
/[0-9]/.test(str) && 
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(str) && 
str.length >=8
```

The other solutions follow a pattern I have seen where people twist themselves into knots trying to write a single regexp for a problem better solved by scanning, testing, or combining regexps.

Comment: So how would I set this string as needing to be at least 8 characters long and include a non alpha numeric character? When I tested your suggestion it still didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the {8,} here ?

There is nothing between the `+` and the `{8,}`

I think you want this : `/^[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+[^A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$/`

Comment: I need it to be at least 8 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

/^[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+[^A-Za-z0-9]+{8,}$/ is wrong (+{8,})
change in

/^[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+[^A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$/